# Call python code from Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I want to run a python code from ruby.
I am [using this gem.](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/)
 Ruby code:

```
require "rubypython"    
RubyPython.start    
fileinput=RubyPython.import("fileinput")
RubyPython.stop
```

I get the error :
rubypython warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems

Ruby code:

```
require "rubypython"

RubyPython.start 

fileinput=RubyPython.import("fileinput")

name=''
name2=""
r=0
i=0
open_file=fileinput.input("lala")
output=open("lalal","w")
for line in open_file:
    keys=line.split()
    length=(len(keys))
    if length==3:       

        if (keys[0]!=name and i!=0):
            output.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(name,name2,r))             
            name=keys[0]
            name2=keys[1]
            r=float(keys[2])        


output.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(name,name2,r))
output.close()

RubyPython.stop
```

I get the error:

```
unique.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_do_cond or ';' or '\n'
unique.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
    if length==3:       
                 ^
unique.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
unique.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
            output.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(name,name2,r))
```

Seems that gem is not working. What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can tell, this allows you to use Python objects in Ruby, but not just insert Python code into the middle of your Ruby code.

Comment: what can allow me to use Python code in the middle of my Ruby code?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such project. Either rewrite your code in Ruby, or call it as a stand-alone script from your Ruby script.

Comment: @Lattyware m... I am not sure if I understand what you mean

Comment: I have clarified in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyPython allows you to use Python objects from within Ruby, but your code has to be valid Ruby code (it just exposes wrapper objects that work with the Python objects in the background). You could translate your code into the Ruby equivalent using this tool, but at that point, you might as well just rewrite it in Ruby, which would be cleaner, more readable, and more efficient.

There is no way, as far as I know, to insert Python code into a Ruby script and have it run. Such a project is pretty out-there and unlikely to be anything approaching efficient.

Either rewrite your Python code as Ruby code, or make your Python code a stand-alone script that you can then [call the Python interpreter](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/) to run it from Ruby. This is naturally only an option if your code doesn't need a ton of interaction with the rest of your application, as all communication will have to happen using stdin/stdout.

Comment: If I rewrite it, do you know a function in Ruby that is equivalent to fileinput in Python? I am dealing with 1-5gb files and I do not want to load thw whole file, I want to be able to load only one line.

Comment: @Katja It's worth noting you don't need `fileinput` in Python to read files lazily, that's the default, as file objects are generators. I'm no Ruby expert, but [this was the first Google result for *lazy ruby file iteration*](http://railsillustrated.com/how-to-be-lazy-in-ruby-and-why-you-should.html).

Comment: I hat some problems with just readlines or readline in Python. It was able to handle files over 4-5 gb. but thanks=)

Comment: @Katja That's because `file.readlines()` produces a list. In Python, you iterate directly over the file: `for line in file:`.

Comment: If the problem is that you don't understand how to do line-by-line I/O in Ruby, then perhaps you should read through the docs for Ruby's IO class. `IO.foreach` does that, as does opening a file and using `ios.each_line`. I've quickly and easily read multi-GB files with Ruby this way.